# Running Jmeter Test in multiple accounts parallelly

Tags: jmeter

I have set of sampler under one Thread Group as

```
TestPlan
   ThreadGroup
      SimpleController
         Login(HTTP Sampler)
         FetchCSRFToken(HTTP Sampler)
      LoopController(Count -> 5)
         Testcase1(HTTP Sampler)
         Testcase2(HTTP Sampler)
         Testcase3(HTTP Sampler)
```

Now I got a requirement to run the above test cases in multiple accounts parallelly.

I googled and find out having Multiple Thread Group is a better idea since I suppose to run it parallelly and I have to pass CSRF token in all test cases header.

Is it possible to have two thread groups without duplicating the test cases inside Loop Controller of Thread Group-1 to Thread Group-2?
Kindly suggest if any other way as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid code duplication - just put the "shared" code under a [Test Fragment](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) and reference it using [Module Controller(s)](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller) where required

In general a Thread Group should represent a logical/business group of users, if you just need to add more users doing the same actions - you can parameterize credentials, URLs, parameters, etc. so each thread will use different set of data on each iteration, the most commonly used approach for parameterization is [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)